# sub-query return more than 1 value this is not permitted when the subquery follows = , >=,>,<,<=

Tags: sql-server

when i insert employee data this error occur
sub-query return more than 1 value this is not permitted when the subquery follows = , >=,>,<,<=

i tried

```
INSERT INTO 
    Transaction_Employee(Memployee_id,
                        Emp_bio_id,
                        des_id,
                        Department_id,
                        Unit_id,
                        etype_id,
                        payment_id,
                        Leave_id,
                        joining_date,
                        resign_date,
                        leave_start_date,
                        Bank_id)
VALUES
(
    @memployee,
    @emp_bio_id,
    (SELECT DISTINCT des_id FROM Setup_designation WHERE des_name=@desig),
    (SELECT DISTINCT Department_id FROM Setup_Department WHERE Depart_name=@deprt),
    (SELECT DISTINCT Unit_id FROM Setup_Unit WHERE unit_name=@unit),
    (SELECT DISTINCT etype_id FROM Setup_Enployeetype WHERE ename=@emp_type),
    (SELECT DISTINCT payment_id FROM Setup_Payment_Type WHERE payment_name=@payment),
    (SELECT DISTINCT Leave_id FROM Setup_Leave WHERE leave_name=@leavename),
    @joining_date,
    @resign_date,
    @leave_startdate,
    (SELECT DISTINCT Bank_id FROM Setup_Bank WHERE bank_name=@bank_name)
)
```

Comment: Try each of your `select` statements individually, and I think you'll find that at least one of them returns more than one value, as the error message says. Obviously if you're trying to insert a single row, having multiple values for one of the columns won't work.

Comment: Not all `SELECT DISTINCT` statements on your query has exactly single result. You may looking for possible `SELECT TOP(1)` to exactly return one result instead.

Comment: The error is very clear. You should refine the where clause of each subquery to only return one record.